# filter out old spam URI from analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

Just launched a new site for a client and trying to exclude all of the old URLs from analytics that came from viagra or similar hacks.

However i can't seem to get a match that makes a difference?

The hacked URIs started with /case-studi/ so trying —

```
^/case-studi/
```

As well as variations. Filter is custom > Exclude > Request URI not case sensitive.

The links i can find via google are like so -

```
Rayh health care pvt ltd viagra - Greengage
www.greengage-env.com/case-studi/rayh-health-care-pvt-ltd-viagra or 

www.greengage-env.com/viagra
```

How can i filter out these results?

Comment: I'm no regex expert, but couldn't you do something like, custom filter for referral and match something like .\/case\-studi\/.

Comment: its not a referral but using custom with 'Request URI'. Tried .\/case\-studi\/.  but still no affect.

Comment: O wait, you're trying to remove data from view. Then you should use segments, filters only work proactively.

Comment: thanks - had a look at segments but can't see a way to exclude results that match 'case-studs'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work? You should select the segment in your reporting tab.

https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=M99M2hMsQXminwlic26W5A

Comment: Erm. Does that link go anywhere?

Comment: It's a template for a segment; open it while you're logged into GA to automatically add it

Comment: It just takes me to my properties list... does this one work for you? http://www.coventrytelegraph.net/whats-on/food-drink-news/great-british-bake-recipes-how-11798176 Thanks by the way!

Comment: Maybe you don't have the required permissions to add segments

Comment: I've added some attempts so can't be that... oops. That link was wrong...

Comment: Works for me on two different instances. Anyway, segments are the way to go.